# Ez-Templates Jenkins Plugin doesn't override the Email-Notification field

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have started to use the "Ez Templates" Plugin and faced some problem.

I have created one template, lets say for example "Template UI". And my 4 jobs are implementing this "Template UI". They doing the same work, but for each of them 4 different persons responsible. That's why, when these 4 jobs are successfully been built, I have to send email notifications to 4 different persons. 
I can't override this field in my jobs:
[image]

I can only configure the SCM part, but not the email notification that I wanted to.
Does somebody know how I can fix it, or maybe somebody knows the plugin that can help me with it.

I just want to send emails from 4 different jobs to 4 different recipients while these 4 jobs are implementing the same 1 Template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody is facing the same problem as I, I have found the answer.
In this case I have used the **"Email-ext plugin"**.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

But first of all you have to go to your **Template configuration**, and create a **"Text-Parameter"** in **General** part.
[image]

Then you go down to
"Post-Build Actions"**>**"Add Post-Build Action"**>**"Editable Email Notification"**>**"Advanced Settings"
[image: enter description]

Go to "Triggers" :
[image]

And there in "Recipient List" you can pass the parameter from above:
[image]

In this way you configure your Template. In all jobs that are implementing this template, you can configure the particular emails that you need.

My Jenkins is in German that's why I attached a lot of screenshots.